# Cross-Origin Request Blocked in angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, slim

I have created a GET function using Slim which is working fine in browser, i.e. when i hit the link, but when I called the same `url` through `angularjs` it is showing error.

```
 "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.example.com/folder_name/getSongs/0/10"
  Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.example.com/folder_name/getSongs/0/10. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
  Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource. (Reason: CORS request failed).
```

slim framework is install in folder_name folder

*my code in index.php of slim are as follows.*

```
//my db functions file
require_once './common/myfunctions.php';

require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/getSongs/:minLimit/:maxLimit', function ($minLimit, $maxLimit) use ($app) {

    $response = $app->response();
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT');
    $response->header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '1000');
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token');

    $response_array = array(); //response will be send

    $songList = getSongsList($minLimit, $maxLimit);

    if (isset($songList) && !empty($songList)) {

        foreach ($songList as $key => $value) {
            $response_array['data'][$key] = $value;
        }
        $response_array['success'] = TRUE;

        $app->status(200); //Ok
    }
    //blank array
    else {
        $response_array = array("success" => TRUE, "data" => NULL);
        $app->status(204); //No Content
    }

    echo json_encode($response_array);
});

$app->run();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use an options route.

```
//...

$app->options('/:anything+', function  () {
    $app->response->header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
});

//...
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a CORS issue, In your PHP file add at top

`header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

You could also specify a list of IP address which it should allow rather than a `*`

Read about more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: I have added this in to my php file on the 1st line
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token');
but it is not working

Comment: when you execute it via browser check if the headers are coming to you using developer tools(in response headers) If not you are putting them in a wrong place

Comment: I have checked it in the chrome, and I'm getting the correct headers are showing.